# Login Logout Tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to implement Login,Logout in Slide Menu using Tableview.I am saving login state boolean in shared preference and updating the title when cell is created.
when i click that label it is printing empty string.How it is possible? 
What i am doing wrong?
Hope you understand my problem.please check the comment in my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
let items = [["***"],["***", "***"], ["***", "***", "***"], ["***","***"],["***"],[""]]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return items[section].count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = menuTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "menuCellIdentifier") as! MenuTableViewCell        
    if(indexPath.section == 5){
        if(self.preferences.bool(forKey: "Loggedin")){
            cell.menuTitle.text = "Logout"
        }else{
            cell.menuTitle.text = "Login"
        }
    }
    else{
         cell.menuTitle.text=items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }
    return cell
}


 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var title_name=items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

//Here is my problem
//When there is text(Login/Logout) in menuTitle it is printing empty string
//How this happen????
    print("title_name "+title_name)
//It print empty String
    var myCell = menuTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell

    if title_name == "Login"
    {        
        print("login clicked")
        //Push to Login view controller and if login is success full update the shared preference
    }

    if title_name == "Logout" {
        print("Logout clicked")          
        Alamofire.request(Common.getLogoutUrl(), method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: NetworkingUtil.getAlamoFireHeader()).responseJSON { (Response) in
            let error = Response.result.error
            let req = Response.request
            let res = Response.response
            let json = Response.data
            SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
            if error != nil {
                if req != nil && res != nil {
                    print(req!)
                    print(res!)
                }

            }else{

                var parsedjson : JSON!
                do {
                    parsedjson = try JSON(data : json!)
                    print(parsedjson)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    // or display a dialog
                }        
              else{                                              
                    self.preferences.set(false, forKey: "Loggedin") 
                    myCell.menuTitle.text = "Login"
                    self.menuTableView.reloadData()
                    //Push to home view controller            
                }
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: did you implement number of sections delegate method

Comment: Yes

  func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 6
    }

Comment: let items = [["***"],["***", "***"], ["***", "***", "***"], ["***","***"],["***"],["Login"]]
when i change the item array like above   if title_name == "Login"
        {
            print("login clicked is printing")
         
        }

Comment: It is because, it's literally an empty string as the array you provided above...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! MenuTableViewCell
    print(myCell.menuTitle.text!)
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
But Still when i click that lable i am getting empty string.
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        var title_name=items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        print("title_name clicked did select"+title_name)}

Comment: Thanks bro...I have to change the order of code in didSelectRowAt method

Comment: @John if got your answer then don’t forget to accept answer